# Dry hopping at the end of fermentation?

Tags: fermentation, secondary-fermentation, dry-hop, dry-hopping, primary-fermentation

First of all I know being impatient is not the way to approach brewing, but I would like to sneak my last batch (as well as the ones I had planned) into a PRO-AM comp in two weeks. I have an session IPA that has been fermenting for two weeks and turning out great, but I am really looking to get the gravity down a couple more points. If I started dry hopping  at the very tail end of fermentation will I still lose a considerable amount of hoppy goodness or because Co2 production has slowed to a crawl am I in the clear to put hops in the beer?

O.G 1.054 +
+ Current gravity 1.020 ++ Dry hop 2 oz. Columbus (planned)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of at least one [professional brewery](http://21st-amendment.com/) that likes to dry hop before fermentation is complete. Their rationale is that the activity of fermentation helps to keep the dry hops in suspension.

So I think you're fine.

Comment: This is a great idea...  The last dry hopping I did, I was thinking to myself...  "wow, if only I could get the hops to come in contact with more beer..."

Answer (score 0):

According to Tasty McD (Sam Adams Longshot winner and multiple award-winning HB'er), he always dry hops for 2-3 WEEKS, starting at the end of fermentation (airlock bumps between 10-15 seconds, usually about 5 days in).  Some worry about the fermentation driving off aromatics, but according to Tasty, it is just a recipe issue (read: add more hops!).

this also helps, according to him, to drive off any oxygen that are on the hop leaves themselves, as hoppy beers oxidize more easily.  Not sure if this is true with pellet hops (or at all), but I'm going to do it on my next IPA to see how it turns out.